# how to set up a checkbox in a qtableview that is using a QSqlRelationalDelegate

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtqsqlrelationaltablemodel

I have set up a qtableview using a QSqlRelationalTableModel which looks like this:

```
self.PersonModel = PersonTableModel()
self.PersonModel.setTable("person")
       
self.PersonModel.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
self.PersonModel.setJoinMode(1)   # LeftJoin
self.PersonModel.setSort(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)      
self.PersonModel.select()

self.tableViewPerson.setModel(self.PersonModel)
self.tableViewPerson.setItemDelegate(PersonDelegate(self))
```

I now have subclassed the QSqlRelationalTableModel and set it up like this:

```
class PersonTableModel(QSqlRelationalTableModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QSqlRelationalTableModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.booleanSet = [10]  # column with checkboxes
        # self.readOnlySet = [1]  # columns which must not be changed

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        value = super(QSqlRelationalTableModel, self).data(index)
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                return Qt.Unchecked if value == 0 else Qt.Checked
            else:
                return QVariant()
        return QSqlRelationalTableModel.data(self, index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                val = 0 if value == Qt.Unchecked else 1
                return QSqlRelationalTableModel.setData(self, index, val, 
        Qt.EditRole)
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return QSqlRelationalTableModel.setData(self, index, value, 
         role)

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags
        if index.column() in self.booleanSet:
            return Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | 
        Qt.ItemIsEditable

        return QSqlRelationalTableModel.flags(self, index)
```

Now it creates a checkbox, the entries are set into the database, but the mapper i am using doesnt work anymore because of this line of coding:

```
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
               return Qt.Unchecked if value == 0 else Qt.Checked
            else:
               return QVariant()
```

Comment: If the last column is just a boolean, you should not need the sql relation at all, since I doubt you have a table that only relates false and true values. In fact, you probably don't need an editor at all, as Qt models already support the `CheckStateRole`. If that state is a string, then subclass the relational model and override the `data()`, if the index column is 10 and the role is `Qt.CheckStateRole`, then read the value with `super().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)` and return `Qt.Checked` or `Qt.Unchecked` depending on the result.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the reply. the last column is a field in sqlite table. type is boolean length one. If I do nothing values set to 0 and 1.

Comment: As said, you need to subclass and override `data()`.

Comment: That may be because the new data is using a different data type (probably, a string): we don't know what database engine you're using, so if it doesn't do any automatical conversion. Try with a basic `print(type(value))` in `data()`, if it is indeed a string, you can add a further checking: if isinstance(value, str) and value.isdigit(): value = int(value)

Comment: the print(type(value)) in data() prints out a <class 'int'>. I guess the mapper can not handle the X in the checkbox. It needs a 0 or 1 to map to the other checkbox.  When i set it up like it shows a checkbox and a 0 or 1 next to the checkbox it maps correctly as it should. So the solution must be: show a checkbox, but not number, map according to checked or unchecked.